# Show that $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] / \langle x_1x_4 - x_2x_3 \rangle$ is an integral domain of dimension $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, krull-dimension

I am stuck at the following exercise from [Gathmann's notes on Algebraic Geometry](https://agag-gathmann.math.rptu.de/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021.pdf) on page 21:

> Let $R = K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] / \langle x_1x_4 - x_2x_3 \rangle$. Show that $R$ is an integral domain of dimension $3$.

While I know the definition of dimension (from page 17 in the above notes):

> The dimension $X \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ is the supremum over all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is a chain
> $$\emptyset \subset Y_0 \subsetneq Y_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq Y_n \subset X$$
> of length $n$ of irreducible closed subsets $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ of $X$.

I do not understand how to apply this definition on $R$. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: The corresponding definition of dimension for a ring $R$ is that the dimension of $R$ is the supremum over all $n$ for which there is a chain of prime ideals $P_0\subsetneq P_1\subsetneq\dots\subsetneq P_n\subset R$. See Lemma 2.27 in the linked notes.

Comment: Do you know that polynomial ring in $n$ variables over a field has dimension $n$?

Comment: Also remembering the correspondence theorem could be a good start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming $K$ is a field. Thus $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ is a UFD and it remains to show that $\langle x_1x_4-x_2x_3 \rangle$ is prime, which just comes down to showing $x_1x_4 - x_2x_3$ is irreducible in $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$, which I'm sure you know how to do. It follows from there that $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/\langle x_1x_4-x_2x_3 \rangle$ is an integral domain.

To show the dimension, recall that by Krull's Hauptidealsatz, we have that $\langle x_1x_4 - x_2x_3 \rangle$ is of height $1$, we have that

$\begin{align*}
\text{dim}(K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)/\langle x_1x_4 - x_2x_3 \rangle) = \text{dim}(K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)) - \text{height}(\langle x_1x_4 - x_2x_3 \rangle) = 4 -1 = 3
\end{align*}$

as desired.

Comment: For your last formula, you're implicitly using something about $A := K[x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}]$ which may not be known to the OP, namely that it satisfies the dimension formula $ht(P) + dim(A/P) = dim(A)$ for all prime ideals $P$ of $A$. I don't think you need to appeal to this fact, which is somewhat sophisticated, I think; you can just exhibit the proper chain of prime ideals $\langle x_{1}x_{4} - x_{2}x_{3} \rangle \subset \langle x_{1}, x_{2} \rangle \subset \langle x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3} \rangle \subset \langle x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4} \rangle$.